# Can't import wxPython on OSX Lion with Python 2.7.3 installed via Homebrew

Tags: python, wxpython, osx-lion, importerror

I can't import `wxPython` on OSX Lion after installing `wxPython` from this package http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.9-osx-2.9.4.0-cocoa-py2.7.dmg.

I also tried to add `wxPython` directories to `PYTHONPATH`, but still, I cant import it. Installer created these folders:

```
/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0
/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode
/usr/local/lib/wxPython
```

I added them onto `PYTHONPATH`, but still no success. Still getting no module called `wx`.

When I tried to install it via pip (`pip install wx`), I was able to import `wx`, but unable to import `wx.App()`, `wx.Frame()` etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue as you, but I was using homebrew and python brew and pip. I posted this in reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1063o1/wx_install_problems_os_x/

Apparently, wx is not the same as wxpython.

I used homebrew and installed wxmac instead to get it working.

It might help a little.

Answer (score 0):

If you can import `wx` then it is working.

How are you trying to import `App` and `Frame` etc?

You only need to do

```
import wx
app= wx.App()
```

or if you do only want to import `App` and `Frame` then,

```
from wx import Frame, App
app = App()
frame = Frame(None)
```

Comment: PLease read my post carefully. I was able to import wx only when I installed it via pipm but only thing i could do was

Answer (score 0):

1. `brew install wxpython`
2. launch python and type `import site; site.getsitepackages()`, you will get the site of site-packages, for example: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'
3. `cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`
4. `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/wxpython/3.0.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx wx`